# CSV code not looping

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I'm trying to make a small Python script to speed up things at work and have a small script kind of working, but it's not working as I want it to. Here's the current code:

```
import re
import csv
#import pdb

#pdb.set_trace()

# Variables
newStock = "newStock.csv" #csv file with list of new stock
allActive = "allActive.csv" #csv file with list of all active
skusToCheck= []
totalNewProducts = 0
i = 0

# Program Start - Open first csv
a = open(newStock)
csv_f = csv.reader(a)

# Copy each row into array thingy
for row in csv_f:
        skusToCheck.append(row[0])

# Get length of array
totalNewProducts = len(skusToCheck)

# Open second csv
b = open(allActive)
csv_f = csv.reader(b)

# Open blank csv file to write to
csvWriter = csv.writer(open('writeToMe.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

# Check first value in first row,first file against each entry in 2nd row in second file
with open(allActive, 'rt') as b:
        reader = csv.reader(b, delimiter=",")
        for row in reader:
                if skusToCheck[i] == row[1]:
                        print(skusToCheck[i]) # output to screen for debugging
                        print(row) # debugging
                        csvWriter.writerow(row) #write matching row to new file
                        i += 1 # increment where we are in the first file
```

Pseudo code would be:

1. Open file one and store all values from column one in `skusToCheck`
2. Check this value against values in column 2 in file 2
3. If it finds a match, (once I have this working, i want it to look for partial matches too) copy the row to file 3
4. If not move onto the next value in `skusToCheck` and repeat

I can't seem to get lines 33 - 40 to loop. It will check the first value and find a match in the second file, but won't move onto the next value from `skusToCheck`.

Comment: You need to reset `i = 0` *inside the `while` loop* or, better, use `for sku in skusToCheck:`.

Comment: If i reset it whithin the loop, how will it keep track of where it is? Im using i to track where in the array the program is.

Comment: Could you clarify - do you want to check every SKU against every line, or only those that appear in the same order as in the file? And what do you mean by *"keep track of where it is"*? (Sorry, that should have read `for` loop.)

Comment: I want it to look at the first sku from skusTocheck[i] (i is set to 0, the first entry), then try and match that sku against any matching skus in the second file. If it finds a match, it copies the row to another file, if not, then i is incremented so it looks at the second entry in skusToCHeck. The i variable is keeping track of where in the array(variable?) to look for the value to search for.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - **do you want to check every SKU against every line?** If so, you need to go back to the start of `skusToCheck` for every `row in reader`.

Comment: Apologies.Yes, each sku needs to be checked against each line. "you need to go back to the start of skusToCheck for every row in reader" COuld you clarify this a little please?

Comment: Then my first comment stands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the hint from jonrsharpe's first comment, i.e. modify your while loop to

```
# Check first value in first row,first file against each entry in 2nd row in second file
with open(allActive, 'rt') as b:
    reader = csv.reader(b, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
    if len(row)>1:
        for sku in skusToCheck:
            if sku == row[1]:
                print(sku) # output to screen for debugging
                print(row) # debugging
                csvWriter.writerow(row) #write matching row to new file
                break
```

This checks if each single `sku` is matching for all of the rows in allActive

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The code you provided still only seems to work on the first item from skusToCheck. The skus that need to be checked are stored in a csv in a columm. could this be affecting code?

Comment: Actually, I was being a noob. Code is on the right track. Thanks.